# Convert list of single elemnt into valud for a df

Tags: pandas, list

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFHNy.png)

I want convert each element that is a list of only one value into that value. Can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas.Series.apply to apply a lambda function to select the first element of each list:

```
for col in ['eta', 'q11']:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```